# Query to get attributes of user defined nested type in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, user-defined-types

I have a user defined type called person_type

```
TYPE person_type AS OBJECT (
  idno           NUMBER,
  name           VARCHAR2(30),
  phone          VARCHAR2(20)
);
```

```
select * 
from all_type_attrs
where owner = 'owner_name'
and type_name = 'person_type'
```

works for the type. But when I have another type called - people_type

```
TYPE people_type AS TABLE OF person_type; -- nested table type
```

and when I try the following query

```
select * 
from all_type_attrs
where owner = 'owner_name'
and type_name = 'people_type'
```

does not return anything. How do I get the attribute(schema) details of the new type - people_type

1. Need to get schema attributes for type - people_type which is `AS TABLE OF` another type
2. What is the use of SYS.ALL_TYPES
3. How do we handle Object types

Comment: Based on the linked duplicate, you can use [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1a29cf753f453bc71c3069902ead9dae)

Comment: Got it. Thank you

Comment: Beyond getting your answer, though, spend a few seconds understanding why the way you were trying to solve your problem was wrong. You expect to see "attributes" of a collection type. Obviously, in your mind, by that you mean the attributes of the members of the collection; the collection ITSELF does not have attributes, only its members do. A simple lookup of the collection type can tell you what type its members are - but you need to do more to, then, follow up and find the members' attributes.